# ASP.NET MVC4 Bootstrap-Typeahead.js Javascript error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, typeahead

I'm building an ASP.NET web app with bootstrap and i'm trying to implement a typeahead and having issues.  I tried following this example: http://jcherryhomes.com/post/2012/12/03/ASPNET-MVC-Using-Twitter-Bootstrap-Typeahead-via-Ajax.aspx

I'm getting a javascript error:
Unhandled exception at line 240, column 13 in localhost:10681/Content/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined or null reference

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (term, process) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Maintenance/GetDistributors")';

            return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }

    });
})
</script>

<input type="text" name="names" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" />
```

Comment: You have got a null reference exception so I would recommend you try doing `console.log(data);` inside the getJSON callback function to see if your even getting that far, do the same for the url so you can debug your code and see where you are getting a null value. Please also let us know what version of Bootstrap you are using.. because the old bootstrap-typeahead is only for v2.3.2

Comment: sorry v2.3.2 and below, its been replaced by http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ in v3